# AspNetCore.Reporting Library has Cache issue

Tags: asp.net-core, dynamic-rdlc-generation

Single Report Works Fine. But While requesting for the other report it gives exception "Index Out of bound". Someone please help me with a working solution.

Comment: Hi @Dawood Jamil, could you please share enough code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Actually .Net Framework supports RDLC reporting. But to render report as Pdf in Asp.Net Core Project I'm using AspNetCore.Reporting Library. Now the Problem is that after generating one report, the report throws exceptions "Index Out Of Bound". This happens due to a cache Issue. For reference here is the link
 https://github.com/amh1979/AspNetCore.Reporting/issues/16

Comment: @Rena I'm stuck on this exception for last two weeks.

Comment: https://github.com/amh1979/AspNetCore.Reporting/issues/16#issuecomment-922505776